# Dynamically select all columns but among ones that start with a certain word exclude all but keep one

Tags: r, dplyr, subset, plyr

I have many data frames that come in such a format:

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:2, Name = 1:2, Gender = 1:2, Group = 1:2, 
                      FORMULA_RULE = 1:2, FORMULA_TRANSFORM = 1:2, FORMULA_UNITE = 1:2, 
                      FORMULA_CALCULATE = 1:2, FORMULA_JOIN = 1:2), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                        -2L))

df2 <- structure(list(ID = 1:2, Name = 1:2, Gender = 1:2, FORMULA_RULE = 1:2, 
    FORMULA_META = c(NA, NA), FORMULA_DATA = 1:2, FORMULA_JOIN = 1:2, 
    FORMULA_TRANSFORM = 1:2, Group = 1:2), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

View:

```
df1
  ID Name Gender Group FORMULA_RULE FORMULA_TRANSFORM FORMULA_UNITE FORMULA_CALCULATE FORMULA_JOIN
1  1    1      1     1            1                 1             1                 1            1
2  2    2      2     2            2                 2             2                 2            2

df2
  ID Name Gender FORMULA_RULE FORMULA_META FORMULA_DATA FORMULA_JOIN FORMULA_TRANSFORM Group
1  1    1      1            1           NA            1            1                 1     1
2  2    2      2            2           NA            2            2                 2     2
```

I want to write a code that would work on all such dataframes in a way that all columns are kept, but among the columns starts with `FORMULA_`, only `FORMULA_TRANSFORM` is selected. Please note that columns that **do NOT** start with `FORMULA_` are **not** always the same, that is to say, I cannot simply write a code that always selects `ID`, `Name`, `Gender`, `Group`, and `FORMULA_TRANSFORM`, because there are some data frames that contain many other columns that do not start with `FORMULA_` which I want to keep.

My **attempt** to solve this problem is this ugly code which **works** as expected:

```
library(tidyverse)
for(i in 1:length(ls(pattern = "df"))){

    get(paste0("df", i)) %>% 
        select(-starts_with("FORMULA"), 
               (names(get(paste0("df", i))) %>% grep(pattern = "FORMULA", value = T))[!names(get(paste0("df", i))) %>% grep(pattern = "FORMULA", value = T)  %in% "FORMULA_TRANSFORM"]) 
    %>% print

}
```

Is there a more straight-forward way to do this?

Comment: Do you have other columns ending with `_TRANSFORM`? Because you could select back your column using `ends_with()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `dplyr` we can use `select` and it's pretty straight forward using `starts_with` and `contains`.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   select(-starts_with("FORMULA_"), contains("FORMULA_TRANSFORM"))


#  ID Name Gender Group FORMULA_TRANSFORM
#1  1    1      1     1                 1
#2  2    2      2     2                 2
```

Let's try with a dataframe without "FORMULA_TRANSFORM" column

```
df3 <- df1
df3$FORMULA_TRANSFORM <- NULL

df3 %>%
   select(-starts_with("FORMULA_"), contains("FORMULA_TRANSFORM"))

#  ID Name Gender Group
#1  1    1      1     1
#2  2    2      2     2
```

With minus sign we are removing the columns that `starts_with` "FORMULA_" and selecting the one with "FORMULA_TRANSFORM". Instead of `contains` we can also use `one_of()` or `matches()` and it would still work.

---

Using base R we can use `grep` with `invert` and `value` set as `TRUE`

```
df1[c(grep("^FORMULA_", names(df1), invert = TRUE, value = TRUE),
                                           "FORMULA_TRANSFORM")]

#  ID Name Gender Group FORMULA_TRANSFORM
#1  1    1      1     1                 1
#2  2    2      2     2                 2
```

This creates a vector of column names where column name doesn't start with "FORMULA_" and we add "FORMULA_TRANSFORM" manually later.

The above method assumes that you always have "FORMULA_TRANSFORM" column in your dataframe and it will fail if there isn't. Safer option would be

```
get_selected_cols <- function(df1) {
    cbind(df1[grep("^FORMULA_", names(df1), invert = TRUE)], 
        df1[names(df1) == "FORMULA_TRANSFORM"])
 }
get_selected_cols(df1)

#  ID Name Gender Group FORMULA_TRANSFORM
#1  1    1      1     1                 1
#2  2    2      2     2                 2


get_selected_cols(df3)

#  ID Name Gender Group
#1  1    1      1     1
#2  2    2      2     2
```